# Quelle serait une autre façon plus jolie de tourner « J’ai été retardé par le passage d’un train » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

Quelle serait une autre façon plus jolie de tourner :

> J’ai été retardé par le passage d’un train. [...à un passage à niveau]

Il s'agit de la justification d’un retard au travail.

Comment: Il vaut mettre la question dans le texte plutôt que dans le titre. De quel passage du train parles-tu ? À un passage à niveau ?

Comment: Oui, en parlant d’un temps d’attente devant un passage à niveau à cause de l’arrivée d’un train.

Comment: « Barrières fermées, pas de train en vue, toujours pareil ensuite, et Monsieur a daigné défiler lentement devant nous un quart d'heure après ! Il y avait un wagon dont les roues cognait sur les rails. » Il y a des chances que toute explication cohérente, vraisemblable avec la réalité contée soit acceptée telle quelle, car originale et invérifiable … ne sert qu'une fois :-)

Comment: Ceci dit, il est difficile de justifier plus de deux minutes de retard avec une telle excuse. Autant parler d'"embarras de circulation", qui regroupe tous les problèmes qu'on peut rencontrer sur la route, embouteillages, travaux, police, passage à niveau...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Je dois mon retard à un train qui a traversé un passage à niveau à la vitesse d'un escargot.
- Un escargot de train à un passage à niveau ! C'est ce qui m'a retardé.

Answer (score 2):

> J'ai été retardé/mon retard s'explique par un long arrêt à un passage à niveau.

La distinction vient sans artifice.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais :

> Excusez mon retard, je le dois à un train qui a mis un temps fou à traverser un passage à niveau.